# Value of standard error from summary in lqmm package

Tags: r, summary

Question is simple: how to get value of standard error, lower bound and upper bound for each variable for each level of tau from summary function in lqmm package?

```
              Value      Std. Error lower bound upper bound  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   value1         13.9770730  0.3399716  13.2938744     14.6603 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor(a)2    value2         -0.6249463  0.0359903  -0.6972716     -0.5526 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor(b)2    value3          0.3511184  0.0500702   0.2504986      0.4517 6.344e-09 ***
```

I would like to get value of 13.977. Is it possibly anyhow?
If I use QR2013SKDHRP$`tau`, then only the first column coefficients and few other values are obtainable, but not standard error, lower bound and upper bound.

Comment: Most `summary` functions return a matrix as a named item in their value. One generally sees these names in the help page. Doesn' t that package document its summary value?

Comment: A while ago, I have learnt that summary and summary.lqm are not identical. Although, at the beginning, summary.lqm was saying errors, hence I used only summary, Now it works. But vignette is very weak and does not mention each possibilty of values relating to summary.lqm.

Comment: When you run `summary` on an object of class `lqm`, you are actually running the `summary.lqm` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `summary.lqmm` function retruns a list with a matrix of values fore each tqu requested. According to the help page this result is in a leaf named `"tTable"`. Using the example on the help page as the starting point:

```
> res <- summary(fitOi.lqmm)
Warning message:
In errorHandling(OPTIMIZATION$low_loop, "low", control$LP_max_iter,  :
  Lower loop did not converge in: lqmm. Try increasing max number of iterations (500) or tolerance (1e-05)

> res$tTable
$`0.1`
                 Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 16.7336088  0.7300274  15.2665637  18.2006538 7.620900e-28
age          0.5221987  0.0783630   0.3647224   0.6796751 2.201244e-08

$`0.5`
                 Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 16.8119676 0.72758041  15.3498401  18.2740952 5.312804e-28
age          0.6188025 0.08742306   0.4431193   0.7944857 5.018630e-09

$`0.9`
                 Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 16.8267888  0.7346688  15.3504165  18.3031611 7.894189e-28
age          0.7961899  0.1008876   0.5934487   0.9989311 2.796707e-10
```

The problems reported in the comments do not seem to relate to the choice of `lqmm` versus `lqm`. You get the same sort of result looking at the output of `summary.lqm` applied to the example on the `?lqm` help page:

```
 fit.lqm
#-------------------
Call: lqm(formula = y ~ x, data = test, tau = p, control = list(verbose = FALSE, 
    loop_tol_ll = 1e-09), fit = TRUE)

Fixed effects:
             tau = 0.25  tau = 0.50  tau = 0.75
(Intercept)  29.322072   29.954761   30.628379 
x             1.124451    1.182257    1.251657 

Degrees of freedom: 500 total; 498 residual
#------------
names(summary(fit.lqm))
#--------------     
[1] "0.25"        "0.50"        "0.75"        "theta"       "scale"       "call"       
 [7] "term.labels" "terms"       "nobs"        "edf"         "dim_theta"   "rdf"        
[13] "tau"         "x"           "y"           "weights"     "levels"      "InitialPar" 
[19] "control"     "tTable" 

summary(fit.lqm)$tTable
 #----------------    
[[1]]
                Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.322072  0.1071627  29.1067201   29.537423 1.089432e-79
x            1.124451  0.2137049   0.6949946    1.553907 3.134769e-06

[[2]]
                Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.954761  0.1001000  29.7536022   30.155919 1.358822e-81
x            1.182257  0.1447352   0.8914013    1.473114 1.057212e-10

[[3]]
                Value Std. Error lower bound upper bound     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.628379  0.0833481  30.4608850   30.795874 5.813793e-86
x            1.251657  0.1736253   0.9027443    1.600571 3.150189e-09
```

Demonstrating how to access the Std.Error column of the first matrix in the output:

```
> summary(fit.lqm)$tTable[[1]][, "Std. Error"]
(Intercept)           x 
  0.1296308   0.2851553
```

If you wanted the "value of standard error, lower bound and upper bound" for the first value of `tau` all in one answer. it would just be:

```
 summary(fit.lqm)$tTable[[1]][, c( "Std. Error", "lower bound",  "upper bound") ]
```

Comment: I cannot use summary.lqmm, because it says: "Error in 1:dim_theta_z : argument of length 0". Therefore, I am forced to use only the summary.lqm function and it has no such a possibility. However, I have no variable to determine that causes presence of random or fixed effects.

Comment: Even, a case you are demonstrating does not work. At me, after calling res$tTable, it shows list with [[1]], ... [[n]] parts that are not accessible into their columns. And res$tTable$`0.1` does not work at all.

Comment: Those are matrices inside the list. You cannot use $ to access matrix columns. Need to use `[`.

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem. I have to use double brackets [[]].

Comment: I showed how to use "[[", so I don't understand the statement that you "have to use "[[".. That delivers the full matrix. Then you need to use "[" after that to access a single column. This is getting a bit discouraging that so far there is no upvote.

Comment: It was meant to my previous experience with this – before I wrote here my question. Then, I tried to use only single bracket instead of double bracket.